# Facebook like box in Persian - wrong margin on the like button

Tags: localization, facebook-likebox

In my website www.bazarak.af I have a like box but the thumbs up icon in the like button is not positioned correctly. It is actually hiding one character.

whats wrong? and how to fix it?

image:
[image]

Comment: Show us the css file of that button for more accurate anwser

Comment: here is it:http://www.bazarak.af/css/style.css

Comment: the only thing that I have modified regarding fb-like-box are these:.main .left .fb-holder{min-height:260px;margin-bottom:15px;}
.main .left .fb-like-box{margin-top:15px;}

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your css. Probly you have the overflow hidden and the button size fixed.